# Can we pass any parameters for the key function which we are using along with sorted function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a an element k and list of lists which I named as A . I have to sort elements in A using sorted function  based on k'th element in A .

Ex :

```
k=1  
A=[[10,20,30],[100,5,300]]
```

Output should be

```
[[100,5,300],[10,20,30]]
```

I can do this easily using below code .

```
def mysort(x):
    return (x[k])
 k=1
 A=[[10,20,30],[100,5,300]]
 print(sorted(A,key=mysort))
```

But what I am asking here is I want to pass the variable k in to function mysort .

Answer (score 2):

[`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is convenient for your *specific* use case:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = sorted(A, key=itemgetter(k))
```

[`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) offers a more general solution:

```
from functools import partial

def mysort(x, index):
    return x[index]

res = sorted(A, key=partial(mysort, index=k))
```

Comment: upvoted for the `partial` solution which is the only solution that answers OP question (as asked).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lambda for that - lambdas are (kindof) anonymous functions:

```
k=1
A=[[10,20,30],[100,5,300]]
print(sorted(A,key=lambda x:x[k]))
```

Output:

```
[[100, 5, 300], [10, 20, 30]]
```

This post [why-are-python-lambdas-useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful) explains it in some more detail and the official documentation is here: [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)
The lambda `lambda x:x[k]`  uses every element of `A` and from it the k-th value to sort your list.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
def mysort(k):
    return lambda x: x[k]
# ...
sorted(A, key=mysort(k))
```

Fortunately for you, this is alrealy implemented in `operator` from the standard library:

```
from operator import itemgetter
k = 1
sorted(A, key=itemgetter(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the function for the key paramerer dynamically using closures:

```
def mysort(k):
  def f(x):
    return x[k]
  return f

k=1
A=[[10,20,30],[100,5,300]]
print(sorted(A,key=mysort(k)))
```